# Regular expression for language

Tags: regular-expressions

Let's have a language $L=\{\omega\in\{a,b,c\}^* | \omega $ contains $ab$ and does not contain $ba\}$ make a regular expression for this language.

I've ended up with this one
$$(a^*(b^*+(cc^{*}a^*))^*)^*ab(b^*+(cc^{*}a^*))^*$$

Is this correct? Does it generate all words containing $ab$ and not containing $ba$ ?

Comment: Does $c^+$ mean $cc^*$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: What do those dots mean?

Comment: $a.a = aa$, as in languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect. It accepts $bab=(a^0(b^1)^1)^1ab$. In the first part of the expression, you want to tie $b$ up to $c$, not $a$ to $c$.

Comment: $(a^*(b^*+(cc^{*}a^*))^*)^0ab(b^1)^1 = abb$

Comment: @DávidKaya How do you get that $b^1$ without $c$? Did you mean to have $(cc^*a^*)^*$?

Comment: there's $+$ in $(b^*+(cc^{*}a^*))^*$

Comment: @DávidKaya, I forgot what that $+$ meant. Fixed now.

Comment: Yea, that was my mistake... If I change the regular expression in my question, will you be ok with that, or do you want me to accept your question?

Comment: @DávidKaya, you should add an answer of your own with a corrected version.